# Know how many people are on a video

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, video-capture

So there it is, I want to get a camera video stream from a server, and be able to know how many people appear on it.

I can install any OS (MAC, Windows, Linux) on my server, use any API (free or paid) and any language (C++, php etc.) to do so.

I already found some interesting things, such as OpenCV but I think it's more useful for face recognizing than to know the number of people in a room...

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a human detector applied on each frame for basic statistic exports:

OpenCV has one already:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

All you have to do is replace the face model with a human body (`_fullbody.xml`):

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades

You can now export some statistics such as how many people per frame there are. To find how many unique individuals appeared in a sequence, you'll need a tracker. From there things get more difficult. You'll have to find something that suits your case. Tip: google for "*multi-target tracking code*" or similar.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use openCV's latent svm detector:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html

with a person model from here: 
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_extra/tree/master/testdata/cv/latentsvmdetector/models_VOC2007